# CORS issue with POST, inconsistent behaviour in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cors

The JavaScript request from http://localhost:8080:

```
function sendMessage() {
   var params =
        'AppKey=' + config.appKey +
        '&MetadataJson=' + encodeURIComponent(config.metadataJson),
       url = 'http://localhost/Controller/Action',
       xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            alert('hit!');
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

Translated to HTTP Request:

```
POST http://localhost//Controller/Action HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 667
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=aoqjuh2xob20qt5jpe2jo01i

AppKey=...
```

The HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 06:17:02 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

BUT: the behaviour in the browser (Chrome) is not consistent. Sometimes `alert('hit!')` gets called as expected, but usually, at the point when `readyState` equals 4, `status` equals 0.

This looks like a CORS issue. To me, it seems that the only header field in the request that is related to CORS is `Origin` and the server responses with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the same value, so everything should be ok from the CORS point of view?

Any advice on how to change the JavaScript or server implementation (ASP.NET MVC)?

UPDATE:

The related HTML:

```
<li class="my-link">
    <a href="">Get Help</a>
</li>
```

... and the JavaScript to connect HTML to `sendMessage()`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('my-link'), i;

    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
        els[i].onclick = sendMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: `This looks like a CORS issue.` - why? `but usually, at the point when readyState equals 4, status equals 0. ` - are you saying that _alert(hit)_ **DOES** get called when readyState === 4 and status === 0 ?

Comment: @JaromandaX: status equals sometimes 0, sometimes 200. The latter is what is expected and then `alert()` gets called. status 0 is a typical result of the browser refusing to pass the result to JavaScript, due to cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was not visible in my original description. What seems to be a working solution is to modify `sendMessage()` to return `false`:

```
function sendMessage() {
    ...
    xhr.send(params);

    return false;
}
```

It would be interesting to know, why this is needed. I found the solution by studying cases where page redirects (assigning `window.location.href`) were failing and the suggested solution was to add `return false` to related form submits. This is not even a form submit...